# Where I can find resources of Google Szl (Sawzall)?

Tags: c++, bigdata

I'm working on kind of legacy code related to Google szl (Sawzall). 
It seems there are not so many resources on their webpage (even no tag for szl here in stackoverflow..lol)
https://code.google.com/p/szl/

Is there any external resources for users to understand the internal of sawzall except reading code line by line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not money resources available on the web and most them comes from google itself.

beside `Slz` official site [code.google.com/p/szl](http://code.google.com/p/szl) and its wiki you can also join [Slz google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/szl-users) and ask question about the code there. and you can find some examples of slz in there.

Also there is a good paper about `Slz` [here](http://research.google.com/archive/sawzall-sciprog.pdf%E2%80%8E)

Comment: Yes I've visited official website but it seems not enough info there. But I will try user group..thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! BTW, why you loose rep adding links?

Comment: @user1192878 Your welcome my friend. I will add more link and resources to my post. I started gaining rep just 2 ours ago ;)